display hierarchical data with MariaDB query?
I am trying to display hierarchical data with MariaDB (V.10.4.32-MariaDB) query, to show relationships,( like list of recipes, corporate org chart or program hierarchy).  I can do some manipulation in PHP if required.  In DB2 I can use CONNECT_BY_ROOT and CONNECT BY PRIOR to make these relationships, but MySQL does not support this vocabulary.
Example: Input
   Parent Child
    A        D
    B        E
    B        G
    E        H 

Output
1.     A
1.1      D
  
2.     B
2.1      E
2.1.1      H
2.2      G

The closest I get with MariaDB is by using a Common Table Expression:
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy_cte AS (
    -- Anchor member: start with the root parent
    SELECT WHPNAM  as parent,
           WHFNAM  as child
    FROM rf_pgm_ref
    WHERE WHPNAM = 'ADDRESSR'  -- Starting parent

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
           h.WHPNAM    as parent,
           h.WHFNAM    as child
        FROM rf_pgm_ref h
    INNER JOIN hierarchy_cte cte ON h.WHPNAM = cte.child
)
SELECT DISTINCT   parent, child
FROM hierarchy_cte
ORDER BY parent, child;


Please clarify whether you are using MySQL or MariaDB, and what version. Query SELECT VERSION(); and add the result to your question above. MySQL and MariaDB are different database products, and they are not compatible. You want a solution that will work on the database you are using, and solution for either MySQL or MariaDB may not be applicable to the other.

actually 10.4.32-MariaDB

some examples here that might be useful...https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/

I've edited this post to make it more clear that you are not using MySQL.

What is wrong with your current query?

This question is similar to: Implement Recursive CTE for Hierarchical Query to MariaDB. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

if ^ doesn't answer your question, can you show sample input/output that matches the schema you use in your cte, since I'm guessing that is your real schema?  how do you decide that child E is 2.1 and G is 2.2 and not the reverse?

ysth: numbering at same level does not really matter,
